# How to get nested JSON data within an array using Java?

Tags: java, arrays, json

I'm trying to get and print the values of `Name` and `StarRating` for each restaurant from the following JSON of which I've taken a snippet (there is more above this, however this is the relevant bit I'm trying to extract.  Full link is available here [API](https://uk.api.just-eat.io/restaurants/bypostcode/cr07pd)):

```json
Restaurants": [
{
  "Id": 89024,
  "Name": "Regina Pizza",
  "UniqueName": "regina-pizza-new-croydon",
  "Address": {
    "City": "Croydon",
    "FirstLine": "309 Lower Addiscombe Road",
    "Postcode": "CR0 6RF",
    "Latitude": 51.382231,
    "Longitude": -0.069915
  },
  "City": "Croydon",
  "Postcode": "CR0 6RF",
  "Latitude": 0.0,
  "Longitude": 0.0,
  "Rating": {
    "Count": 561,
    "Average": 5.18,
    "StarRating": 5.18
  }
```

I have the following method to get the data:

```java
public static String parse(String responseBody) {
    JSONArray restaurants = new JSONArray(responseBody);
    for (int i = 0; i < restaurants.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject restaurant = restaurants.getJSONObject(i);
        String name = restaurant.getString("Name");
        int rating = restaurant.getInt("StarRating");
        System.out.println("Restaurant: " + name + " Rating: " + rating);
    }
    return null;
}
```

1. When running the code, I get an error indicating a `JSONArray` must start with '['.
2. I've tried to find similar examples of nested JSON, but I'm unable to find a relevant example.

Answer (score 1):

[Undercore-java](https://github.com/javadev/underscore-java) will help.

```
    String json = "{\"Restaurants\": [\n" +
            "{\n" +
            "  \"Id\": 89024,\n" +
            "  \"Name\": \"Regina Pizza\",\n" +
            "  \"UniqueName\": \"regina-pizza-new-croydon\",\n" +
            "  \"Address\": {\n" +
            "    \"City\": \"Croydon\",\n" +
            "    \"FirstLine\": \"309 Lower Addiscombe Road\",\n" +
            "    \"Postcode\": \"CR0 6RF\",\n" +
            "    \"Latitude\": 51.382231,\n" +
            "    \"Longitude\": -0.069915\n" +
            "  },\n" +
            "  \"City\": \"Croydon\",\n" +
            "  \"Postcode\": \"CR0 6RF\",\n" +
            "  \"Latitude\": 0.0,\n" +
            "  \"Longitude\": 0.0,\n" +
            "  \"Rating\": {\n" +
            "    \"Count\": 561,\n" +
            "    \"Average\": 5.18,\n" +
            "    \"StarRating\": 5.18\n" +
            "  }" +
            "}]}";
    U.<List<Map<String, Object>>>get(U.fromJsonMap(json), "Restaurants").forEach(
            restaurant -> System.out.println(restaurant.get("Name") + " "
                + U.get(restaurant, "Rating.StarRating"))
    );

// output
// Regina Pizza 5.18
```

Comment: Could you add a bit more context to this? I'm struggling, thanks.

Comment: I proposed use alternative library to extract data from Json.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Java's [JsonPath](https://www.baeldung.com/guide-to-jayway-jsonpath)

And do something like (might need some tweaking)

```
Restaurants[name][StarRating]
```